# When does NSF update the status date?

Tags: funding, nsf

I have submitted a proposal to NSF about 9 months ago, and the status of the proposal in Fastlane is "pending" with the last update being the day after it was submitted. Does it mean that it has not been reviewed yet? I have heard that when a proposal is reviewed by a panel, the status date gets updated even though the status might remain the same.

Comment: Have other awards been made in response to this solicitation?

Answer (score 2):

It has been reviewed but a decision has not been made. So it is "pending".

Comment: Since decisions are supposed to be made within 6 months of submission in most cases, the process is running longer than normal.  This could mean that your proposal is a borderline case that is still being considered.  Or, it could just mean that the whole process is taking longer than normal.